# Apache alias directive

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to set up simpleSAML.php but I am running into an issue with the Apache Alias directory. I have successfully used Alias so that when the user visits domain.com/auth then it uses the folder /var/saml/www.

However, for some reason it just lists the contents of the folder /var/saml/www rather than running the index.php file.

I have included the relevant virtual host below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin helpdesk@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/open
    ServerName open.domain.com
    ErrorLog logs/open.domain.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/open.domain.com-access_log common
    Alias /auth/ /var/saml/www
    Alias /auth /var/saml/www
    <Directory /var/saml/www>
            Options All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following line to your config:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

This way apache knows it has to parse the files using php.

P.S. I think you may have to restart Apache rather than a reload.

**Update**

As [Alfabravo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236345/alfabravo) commented:

> Agree. He also needs to check the DirectoryIndex directive and add index.php to it

Comment: Agree. He also needs to check the DirectoryIndex directive and add index.php to it

Comment: Problem solved and my complete own stupidity for not checking the Apache error logs (ironic since it p's me off when people don't check their logs). By not adding a trailing slash to the /var/saml/www then Apache was trying to load /var/saml/wwwindex.php. Stupid!